# Django duplicate value violates unique constraint using Objects.create()

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this object for save files:

```
class File(Base):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, default="arquivo", verbose_name=_('Title'), blank=False)
    filename = models.FileField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('File'), help_text=_("Select the logo file."), blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Slug'), blank=False, null=False)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name=_('Extension'), blank=True, null=False)
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Mimetype'), blank=True, null=False)
    size = models.IntegerField(blank=False, verbose_name=_('Size'), null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = self.filename
        self.extension = self.filename.url.split('.')[-1]
        self.slug = slugify(self.filename)
        self.mimetype = self.filename.file.content_type
        self.size = self.filename.file.size
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        # rename the file to new id pattern
        file_id = ('file_%019d' % self.id)
        current_directory = os.path.dirname(self.filename.path)
        os.rename(self.filename.path, f'{current_directory}/{file_id}')
        self.filename = file_id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The method save() it works when i add one file by admin page, the FileAdmin:

```
@admin.register(File)
class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, Base):
    form = FileModelAdminForm
    
    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        return Base.custom_save_model(self, request, instance, form, change)
```

But, when i try create a File objects using `File.objects.create(filename=file, user=request.user)` return IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_file_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(`id_number`) already exists.

This is the code:

```
number_file = request.FILES.get('number_file')
f = File.objects.create(filename=number_file, user=request.user)
```

The object is created in database, but without update the filename. The problem is in the second `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`, but why this it work in normal insertion on Django Admin Page?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you calling save method twice so when calling it again it throw Integratiy error
so rewrite save as follow and remove first  `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = self.filename
    self.extension = self.filename.url.split('.')[-1]
    self.slug = slugify(self.filename)
    self.mimetype = self.filename.file.content_type
    self.size = self.filename.file.size
    super().save(*args, **kwargs) 
    # rename the file to new id pattern
    file_id = ('file_%019d' % self.id)
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(self.filename.path)
    os.rename(self.filename.path, f'{current_directory}/{file_id}')
    self.filename = file_id
    self.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The first `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` is to create `self.id` number. Removing the line, result in "%d format: a real number is required, not NoneType" in `file_id = ('file_%019d' % self.id) `. I just don't understand why it works when i use the admin page to create file.

Comment: so remove the second super.save(*args, **kwargs) and replace it with self.save()

Comment: Didn't work either, but replace it with `self.save_base()` it worked. What's the difference between `self.save()` and `self.save_base()`?